# Maximal ideals of a subring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification

What are the maximal ideals of $R_5=\{x\in\mathbb{Q}|x=a/b,5\nmid{b},a,b\in\mathbb{Z} \}\subset\mathbb{Q}$?
I am thinking that they are of the form $R_5(x)$ with x$\in\mathbb{Z}$ since if $I$ a maximal ideal then $I=R_5(a/b)$ but $a/b=a*1/b$ and $b,1/b\in R_5$. Is this correct?

Comment: Note that $3$ is a unit of $R_5$ as $1/3\in R_5$. Therefore $3$ and $1$ generate the same ideal. As do many others. But, yeah. All the ideals are generated by integers - for the reason you observed (+1 for that alone).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen In order to determine exactly the maximal ideal would the condition $x\not\equiv 0\mod{5} $ suffice or there are other integers except the units that will give the same ideal?

Comment: Those are all units, so the ideal they generate is the entire ring. Remember that a maximal ideal has to be a proper subset of the ring.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes. So I need only to consider the units, there isn't something more than that right?

Comment: No. For the purposes of generating a maximal ideal you need to throw away the units and work with the rest of them.

Comment: For posterity: this ring is called $\mathbb{Z}_{(5)}$, or $\mathbb{Z}$ *localized* at (the prime ideal) $(5)$ - it is, in particular, a local ring

Comment: Sorry, if you feel like I deserted you. There was a pause for a few minutes, and I thought that you were deep in though. Well, another teacher hopped in, so it ended well :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a step in the right direction, however not all $xR_5$ are maximal ideals, in fact there is just one $x$ satisfying this.

To see this:

Consider intersections of the form $\mathfrak a = \mathfrak m \cap \mathbb Z$, for a maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$ of $R_5$. What can you say about $\mathfrak a$?

Then consider the ideal $\mathfrak a R_5$. Is this prime/maximal? What can you say about the elements not contained in $\mathfrak a R_5$?

Comment: Then $\mathfrak{a}$ would be a maximal ideal in $\mathbb Z$?

Comment: Yes. But you can tell much more about $\mathfrak a$, i.e. you can find it's generator -- there is one blatantly obvious choice for the generator, you just have to argue why other choices don't work, i.e. contradict the maximality of $\mathfrak m$.

Comment: It will be a prime number. Is there something more? I can't follow your argument but I will work on that. There is only one $x$ such that $xR_5$ is maximal?

Comment: i.e., as Jyrki Lahtonen remarked under your first message, 3 doesn't work, because $1/3$ is a unit in $R_5$. You have to find a suitable prime $p$, such that $1/p$ is not a unit. So, yeah, there's just one $p$ with $pR_5$ maximal.

Comment: For any prime $p\neq 5$ we have that $1/p$ is a unit. For $p=5$, $5\in R_5$ but $1/5$ is not in $R_5$. I think I understand now. If $xR_5$ maximal ideal and $x$ not a unit in $R_5$ then the only case is $x=5$ since $x$ must be a prime for $xR_5$ to be maximal.

Comment: Yeah, along a similar line of argumentation you can show that $5R_5$ is a maximal ideal. Because all maximal ideals have $(5)$ as their intersection with $\mathbb Z$, and therefore necessarily contain $5R_5$ in them, there cannot be another maximal ideal of $R_5$, because else it would contain the maximal ideal $5R_5$ properly, i.e. it would contradict the maximality that we have just establishe.d.